# Can HazelCast MapStore be implemented in Client Side?

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am going to use HazelCast MapStore in my project. I have one HazelCast server and some other client projects. Can I implement MapStore class like as http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/map-persistence.html in Client Project?

My concern is about Configuration. I found that I can not set or change HazelCast configurations in client-side. What about the configuration of the MapStore?

Answer (score 1):

No data is stored on Hazelcast members only, so is the MapStore implementation executed. It is not possible to setup a MapStore on client side for that reason. Why do you want that to be a client side responsibility? It doesn't really make sense, so I guess you try to achieve something which is not exactly correct. Can you try to elaborate a bit more on what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You may hack-around by using MapStoreFactory on each node that can load appropriate configuration let's say over HTTP from some server accessible by each node.